# Code showing "TypeError: string indices must be integers" overflow but still producing output. Something to do with json file

Tags: python, json

I'm new to python, and have a function (A) that pulls dictionaries from a list and converts them into a legible format. It was running perfectly fine but now when I run it I get a Type error *after* it spits out the formatted messages. This only happens when I try to utilize the json file I'm attempting to use to save the data I input.

I've isolated the function (B) that is causing the problem (it runs before function A so A can access all saved data), given it's the one that imports saved data from the json file my guess is that I'm doing that wrong in some way.

**Here's the function that formats the data (function A):**

```
def print_anomaly(anomaly):
    print(
        "---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
    print(color.BOLD + "Anomaly Codename: " + anomaly['name'] + color.END)
    print("Anomaly Room #: " + anomaly['room'])
    print("Behavior: " + anomaly['type'])
    print("Threat Type:", end=' ')
    for threat in anomaly['threat class']:
        print(threat, end=' ')
    print("\n"
          "Anomaly Description: " + anomaly['properties'])
```

(the sub function is the one having issues but it does run through this one to form a list)

```
def list_anomalies(filter = ''):
    if filter:
        print("Feature in progress")
    else:
        for anomaly in set(anomaly_bank):
            print_anomaly(anomaly)
```

**Here's the function that seems to be messing with it (Function B):**

```
def load():
    with open('anomaly_data.json') as json_file:
        data = json.load(json_file)
        anomaly_bank.append(data)
```

**Here's what it spits out after being prompted**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Anomaly Codename: The Feild
Anomaly Room #: 0
Behavior: Anomaly is consistently passive
Threat Type: None 
Anomaly Description: Presence felt within the bounds of the research facility since inception. Source and cause unknown.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\JSF71\python_attempts\anomaly_bank.py", line 125, in <module>
    print_anomaly(anomaly)
  File "C:\Users\JSF71\python_attempts\anomaly_bank.py", line 55, in print_anomaly
    print(color.BOLD + "Anomaly Codename: " + anomaly['name'] + color.END)
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Comment: Have you looked/printed at `anomaly` when its passed to `print_anomaly` and confirmed that its a `dict`?

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I have found more information. I'll update the post once I have a more solid grasp on what's going on @Plagon